# How do I determine the equation when I have the given inputs and the given answer for picture frame matting cuts?

Tags: geometry, polynomials

I'm trying to determine the equation to calculate the measurement of my [picture frame matting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_(picture_framing)) cut by working backwards.

Although I can **manually** measure the cut physically - I am in the process of **automating** the process.  I made this example into visual form to show you what I'm referring to:

Frame Width and Height: `16" X 20"`

[Visual Representation of the Picture Frame with dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAlqj.jpg)

Picture Width and Height : `11" X 17"`.  Please note the [MAT OVERLAP](https://www.frameiteasy.com/learn/custom-picture-framing-quarter-inch-overlap/) in the image of `1/4` as well:

[Visual Representation of the Picture Frame dimensions with the Image dimensions & Mat Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyJP1.jpg)

Based on those three inputs (Frame Size, Picture Size, and Mat Overlap) - it equates to the following answer:

[The answers are in RED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld6u2.jpg)

The answers in red applies to where to make the appropriate razor blade cut using the following ruler guide:

[The ruler only goes up to 6"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UF0R.jpg), but it serves as the basis where to move the mat when making the cut.

In conclusion, I respectfully ask for direction of what the equation would be if I can already know the **inputs**:

> Frame Size = `16" X 20"`
> Picture Size = `11" X 17"`
> Mat Overlap = `1/4"`

And that I know the **answer**:

> Width = `1 5/8"`
> Height = `2 5/8"`

Then I'll be able to make my mathematical cut with those answers by sliding the mat board Width to the `1 5/8"` mark on the ruler I attached to this post which will allow me to make my cut.  The same with the .

---

**EDIT 5/20/2022**

I have an additional issue that pertains to or is practically related, so I felt adding information to this initial question will strengthen it.

The user has three choices:

1. Single Mat
2. Double Mat
3. Triple Mat

The concept of the calculator is to automate the measurement for the user as to where to make their cut when making a mat for a particular picture when framing it.  Therefore, for each of the choices - the solution is to determine where to make the cut on the `Width` and `Height` of the mat.

The accepted solution/answer provided to my initial question is perfect for choice #1 "Single Mat" (which was my only initial question).

However, I need help determining the equation when I have two mats (Double Mat) as opposed to one.  When there are two mats the `Mat Overlap` is set to `0` because the `Bottom Mat` takes its place.  But, it changes where you make the cut because now you're dealing with two mats taped together based on the [6" ruler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhZsY.jpg) like above.

Here's a better visual to reflect what's going on:  [Double Mat Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Hhc.jpg)

What I have been able to determine is the answer, but I am having trouble determining the equation for the answer.

### The Given

Width of the frame $w_f=16$, Height of the frame $h_f=20$.

Width of the picture $w_p=11$, Height of the picture $h_p=17$.

Mat Overlap $o=0$, Bottom Mat $m_b=\frac14$

### The Solution

The solution consists of measurements for two mats because this was a "Double Mat" choice.

1. TOP MAT:  $w=1\frac12$, $h=2\frac12$
2. BOTTOM MAT:  $w=1\frac34$, $h=2\frac34$

All in all, I was able to provide the complete given and solution, but I've reached a stuck point determining the equations for TOP MAT and BOTTOM MAT.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to work backwards to create the equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width of the picture is $w_p=11$, the width of the frame is $w_f=16$, and overlap is $o=\frac14$. Then $$w=\frac12(w_f-w_p+o)=\frac12\left(16-11+\frac14\right)=2\frac58$$
Similar, for height:
$$h=\frac12(h_f-h_p+o)=\frac12\left(20-17+\frac14\right)=1\frac58$$

Comment: I hope I can say thank you so much for this.  As this did exactly what I needed.  I just can't thank you enough..  Seriously, great and correct answer.

Comment: I hope you're doing well.  I added an additional edit to my original question that I was, respectfully, hoping you'd take a look at.  I respect you for helping me previously, so if there's something I left out or if the question can be better then please tell me.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the changes right, but it seems like you take the original overlap of 0.5", and you divide that into two. You get then 1/8" added to the bottom mast, and 1/8" subtracted from the top.

Comment: I changed what I was trying to articulate to be more clear. Does my question make better sense now?  Only if you have time of course.  Thanks again.